# URL configuration in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have a Django project in which the HTML page has a simple GitHub link. 

 `<a href="www.github.com">Github</a>` 
When I click on it, the URL it gets redirected to is "localhost/app/github.com" 
Can you please explain why is it happening and what should I do to correct it?

Comment: try adding [protocol] `http://` (or https) at the beginning of URLs

Comment: Thanks a lot @O95

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Django, but is standard HTML.

You need to put the full URL, including protocol:

```
<a href="https://www.github.com">Github</a>
```